# How to forward ports for a running docker container?

Tags: docker, port, vscode-remote

Using VSCode Remote Containers, one can work inside a container. When one then opens up e.g. Jupyter Lab or Tensorboard, it will automatically forward the relevant ports to the host. How can I do the same thing manually via CLI (and/or neovim)?

I'm aware of the port forwarding syntax *when starting* docker containers, but this cannot be applied to already running containers AFAIK.

Comment: The normal approach to this is in fact to stop and delete the existing container and `docker run` a new one with the right options.  It's no different from realizing you started a non-container process with the wrong command-line arguments.